# sql DB calculation moving summary‏‏‏‏‏

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate moving summary‏‏‏‏‏:

```
Total amount:100
first receipt: 20
second receipt: 10
```

the first row in calculation column is a difference between total amount and the first receipt: 100-20=80

the second row in calculation column is a difference between the first calculated_row and the first receip: 80-10=70

The presentation is supposed to present receipt_amount, balance:

```
receipt_amount | balance
20 | 80
10 | 70
```

I'll be glad to use your help
Thanks :-)

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Oracle/SQLServer/MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really give us much information about your tables and how they are structured.

I'm assuming that there is an `orders` table that contains the total_amount and a receipt_table that contains each receipt (as a positive value):

As you also didn't specify your DBMS, this is ANSI SQL:

```
select sum(amount) over (order by receipt_nr) as running_sum
from (
    select total_amount as amount 
    from orders 
    where order_no = 1
    union all
    select -1 * receipt_amount
    from the_receipt_table
    where order_no = 
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all- thanks for your response.

I work with Cache DB which can be used both SQL and ORACLE syntax.

Basically, the data is locaed in two different tables, but I have them in one join query.
Couple of rows with different receipt amounts and each row (receipt) has the same total amount.
Foe example:

Receipt_no  Receipt_amount  Total_amount    Balance
1   20  100 80
1   10  100 70
1   30  100 40
2   20  50  30
2   10  50  20

So, the calculation is supposed to be in a way that in the first receipt the difference calculation is made from the total_amount and all other receipts (in the same receipt_no) are being reduced from the balance

Thanks!